Matrix Multiplication with Templated Class
I'm trying to program matrix multiplication with the following class declaration of a matrix:
template<class T, int rows, int cols>
class matrix {
private:
    T m_data[rows * cols];
    int m_rows;
    int m_cols;
public:
    //constructors
    matrix() : m_cols(rows), m_rows(cols) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            m_data[i] = T(); //default constructor of data type
    }

    matrix(const matrix& other) : m_cols(other.m_cols), m_rows(other.m_rows) {
        for (int i = 0; i < other.size(); i++)
            m_data[i] = other.m_data[i];
    }

    //other functions...

Here is my attempt:
matrix<T, rows, int> operator*(const matrix<T, cols, int>& RHS) const { //error referenced below refers to this line
        if (m_cols != RHS.m_rows) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Matrix dimensions must match for multiplication!");
        }

        matrix<T, rows, int> toReturn;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < RHS.m_cols; ++j) {
                toReturn(i, j) = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < cols; ++k) {
                    toReturn(i, j) += (*this)(i, k) * RHS(k, j);
                }
            }
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

The errors I'm getting are:
Error C2993 'int': is not a valid type for non-type template parameter 'cols'
In main.cpp, I am attempting to use the function as such:
matrix<int, 2, 2> m1;
m1.set(0, 0, 1);
m1.set(0, 1, 2);
m1.set(1, 0, 3);
m1.set(1, 1, 4);

matrix<int, 2, 1> m2;
m2.set(0, 0, 1);
m2.set(1, 0, 1);

matrix<int, 2, 1> m3 = m1 * m2;

The error I get now is:
C2679 binary '*': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'matrix<int,2,1>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

The matrix template declaration is template<class T, int rows, int cols>. In the operator* function you use matrix<T, cols, int>. Does that match? What are you really trying to do?

@Someprogrammerdude I don't even know anymore I've been going at this for so long and I've just resorted to trying nonsensical things

For the argument, perhaps you want matrix<T, cols, rows>? Now think about what the function should return.

Or, if you want arbitrary columns and rows for the argument, then make operator* a template itself: template<std::size_t rhs_rows, std::size_t rhs_cols> actual_return_type_here operator*(matrix<T, rhs_rows, rhs_cols> const& rhs) { ... }

Side note: the default constructor doesn’t need that loop. The compiler will default-construct the array elements.

@AryanMP matrix(const matrix& other) -- Wrting a user-defined version of this function is unnecessary, and you also need not write a user-defined assignment operator or destructor, as the default versions of these functions are adequate.   Don't write functions that do not need to be written -- doing so just leaves it more of a chance that you introduce bugs.

T m_data[rows * cols]; --> std::array<T, rows * cols> m_data;.  Then the matrix constructor is simply matrix() : m_data{} {}, and as mentioned in the answer given by @Evg, you don't need m_rows or m_cols.

int rows and int cols are template parameters, which means they are part of the type system and exist for the compiler but not in the compiled code (no types exist in C++ compiled code). int m_rows; and int m_cols; are data members so they do exist in the compiled code. Having both in the same program makes no sense at all, so choose one and delete the other. Either the number of rows and columns in a matrix are part of the type system or they are not, it can't be both. It's like the difference between std::vector and std::array.

You're going in the right direction. However, using int for a non-type template parameter makes no sense. What you're looking for is an operator* function template. It's probably better to make it a free function instead of a member one:
template<class T, int rows, int dim, int cols>
matrix<T, rows, cols> operator*(const matrix<T, rows, dim>& m1, const matrix<T, dim, cols>& m2) {
    matrix<T, rows, cols> res;
    // calculation matrix elements of res
    return res;
}

Because dimensions are encoded into a matrix type, you don't need any runtime checks, a compiler will do it for you - there will be simply no match for operator* if dimensions don't agree, e.g.
error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'matrix<int, 2, 2>' and 'matrix<int, 3, 1>')

Also note that because dimensions are part of a type, you don't really need m_rows and m_cols data members. Use rows and cols template parameters.
